# Android Bottom Sheet Dialog Fragment distance from top

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, dialogfragment

I have a `BottomSheetDialogFragment` and when i add a new fragment that is bigger from my screen is going to the top. But i want to add an offset so the whole bottom sheet leave space to the back so i can see my navigation bar.

I tried to add `peekHeight = resources.displayMetrics?.heightPixels - X` where x is an integer but does nothing.

I always want to have `isfitToContents = true` which is true by default and `state = State.EXPANDED`

How can i achieve this? Thank you

Comment: sorry for the confusion please remove the changes I said before and I think that your peekHeight is not working because you must have a recycler view inside the bottomsheetdialog try giving a fixed height to it and it its not the case then please share your whole BottomSheetDialogFragment code along with the xml file.